# Don't hide date on button click when page refresh

Tags: javascript

I want to print the date when last time clicked on a button. It's actually working, but it's gone on page refresh but I don't want to hide it. How can I do it?

```html
<input onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()" type="submit" name="Button" value="Button" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: you can store in localStorage https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will work, you can check the codepen [date and time of button clicked](https://codepen.io/dileepthomas1993/pen/qyQGWo)  after clicking the button just refresh you will get the new date and time.

```js
function storeDate() {
   var currentDate = Date();
   localStorage.setItem("dateofButton", currentDate)
}

(function(){
  if(localStorage.dateofButton){
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = localStorage.dateofButton
  }else{
    // its empty
  }
})()
```

```html
<input onclick="storeDate()" type="submit" name="Button" value="Button" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have this at the end of a Form, so using the type `submit` submits the parent form, resulting in either a reload or a being redirected to the website specified in the `action` attribute of the form.

Either remove the `type="submit"` and make it a `type="button"` or `return false` from the onclick handler:

Input type button:

```html
<input onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()" type="button" name="Button" value="Button" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Returning false:

```html
<form action="something">
  <input onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date(); return false;" type="button" name="Button" value="Button" />
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution with localStorage, mentioned in comments, would look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#demo").innerHTML = localStorage.date;
});

$("#buttonId").click(function() {
  localStorage.date = Date();
});
```